# Checking for a specific character in a string

Tags: python, string

I have a string `Words="Lights;Control;On;Off"`

I need a `While True:` cycle, which will check for the ; and print me only the words, without ;.

Any ideas?

Comment: what about a `Words.split(';')` ?

Comment: Check for `;` with `if ';' in Words:`

Answer (score 3):

why while true ?
use this

```
Words.split(';')
```

output:

```
['Lights', 'Control', 'On', 'Off']
```

or if you want working with loop use this method :

```
s= ""

for i in Words:
    if i !=';' :
        s+=(i)
    if i ==';':
        s+=' '

print s
```

output:

```
'Lights Control On Off'
```

**note 1**: in ( method 1 ) your output is a list however you can convert it to string :

```
for i in Words.split(';'):
    print i
```

output:

```
Lights
Control
On
Off
```

Or if you want to print this output in one line do this :

```
for i in Words.split(';'):
    print i,
```

output:

```
Lights Control On Off
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to supplement the above response, you might use:

```
Words="Lights;Control;On;Off"
frags = Words.split(';')
for each in frags:
    print each,
```

remove the comma if you want a line return between each word.

If this is not what you are looking for, supplying more examples of the string assigned to "Words" would be useful and help us to give you the right answer, but certainly based on the information supplied so far, the answers/suggestions made would seem to suffice.

Answer (score 0):

```
ind = 0
word = "Lights;Control;On;Off"
word2 = ""
While True:
    if ind == len(word): break
    if word[ind] != ";":
        word2 += word[ind]
    ind += 1
```